# Div id in Drupal menu items

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-navigation

In Drupal main menu I am creating a menu item. In the path field I want to specify div id instead of path of the node. Is this possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
You couldn't do just `#divid`, in path, but you could `node/19#divid` and even `<front>#divid` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be possible out-of-the-box, but you should be able to pull it off by using the Menu Token module.
https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token

Once you enable the module, you can use a token in your path for the current page, and then append your fragment to it. For example:
[current-page:url]#your-element-id